# Magento: Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "1" already exist

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

After I migrate my Magento shop from one hosting provider to another one. Before I start to migrate a delete all my test orders and put counter of order number to 0. 
I have big problem. When I want to go in back office into sales->order I get an error "*There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 213759415*"

If I go into var/report and open file "213759415" I see 36 lines the first one are:

a:5:{i:0;s:64:"Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "1" already exist";i:1;s:5345:"#0 /usr/home/xxx/domains/xxx.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))

I have Magento 1.7.0.2

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: You'll need to describe what "delete all my test orders and put counter of order number to 0." means to you before anyone can help.

Comment: Seems like some customization joins order item table or any other that has more than one value for a single order. In this case MySQL result set contains more than one row with the same id.

Comment: I use this two script for delete test orders http://magentoxhtml.com/magentotips/how-to-delete-magento-test-orders.html http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/delete-test-orders-in-magento/ for delete test products I use this: http://magentoxhtml.com/magentotips/how-to-delete-magento-test-products.html and for change order number and prefix I use this: http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/#comment-1250 . Hope I give you enough information, that you give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in db, tabel called "onestepcheckout" where I forgot to delete test orders.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you properly deleted all test orders.

You can use the following module to do this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/asperience-deleteorders.html

Comment: This module will be fine if I don't get an error when I go into sales->orders.

Comment: Please let us know what error you get and we will try and help you.

Comment: p.s. here is more detailed instructions on deleting test orders: http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-delete-magento-test-orders-from-a-magento-store/